# Stuck with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm stuck with a regex. I have the line below

```
blah blah blah; Installation started ; END OK; Execution Return Code: 0   ;
```

I'm trying to capture the return code. But there are some return codes that has a minus sign front of it. example `-2231134`

I can't seem to come up with a regex that will capture if the return code has a minus front of it or not.

The regex below works if there is a minus sign front of it. If I remove the dot it works with no minus sign.

```
(Execution Return Code:\D.\d+)
```

Comment: use :- `Execution Return Code:\s*[-]?\d+`

Comment: `Execution Return Code:\s*-?\d+`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/fU7gN8/2

Comment: Or `Execution Return Code:[^;]*` since the field separator seems to be `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the whole field, since the fields separator seems to be `;`, I would recommend using `Execution Return Code:[^;]*`.

If you just want to retrieve the number (with its optional sign), assuming the number of spaces is variable, I would use either :

- the first group of `Execution Return Code:\s*(-?\d+)` if selecting a group is easy
- the result of `(?<=Execution Return Code:)\s*-?\d+` if using lookbehind is possible (note that it may still return leading spaces since lookbehinds must be fixed-width)

Answer (score 0):

```
"/Execution Return Code:\s*(-\d+)/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess easiest is to just do the following

```
Execution Return Code: (\S)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @rock321987

(Execution Return Code:\D*([-]?\d+))

gives me the correct return code.

Thank you everyone.